# neither stop nor slow down our car

Tags: conjunctions

> 1.We neither stop nor slow down our car.
>
> 2.We neither stop our car nor slow down it.

Which is suitable for correlative conjunction?

Comment: Both are equally fine, although the second should be "nor slow it down".

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is correct.

Option 2 is incorrect. But, if we change it to:

> We neither stop our car nor slow it down.

It is now correct, and has the same meaning as the first option.